# Powershell argument passing to function seemingly not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I sense that I am doing something silly, but here is the issue:

```
Function getPropertyOfFile($a, $b, $c)
{
    $a.GetDetailsOf($b, $c)
}
```

If I pass $a, $b, $c variables that are appropriate to the function, it fails saying that

> "Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'GetDetailsOf'."

However, if I directly replace $a, $b, $c with the arguments that I was passing, and then try to run that, it works fine.

What the heck is going on?

**Note:** I am using powershell ISE, and am inputting the function to powershell by copy/pasting it into the console. I have also been working under the assumption that if I input a new function with the same name, it would overwrite. Is there a better way to just have PS read from the .ps1?

**Edit:** I am trying to wrap the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420055/enumerate-file-properties-in-powershell/9420165#9420165) into functions.

**Edit 2:**

```
Function getPropertyOfFile $a $b $c
{
    $a.GetDetailsOf($b, $c)
}
```

Gives an `Missing function body in function declaration.
At line:1 char:28` error.

Comment: You need to show the code you are passing to the function... But try: `$a[0].GetDetailsOf($b, $c)`

Comment: I am passing the $shellfolder, $shellfile, variables that were defined in the post I linked to, and property is just a number

Comment: No you had the `function getPropertyOfFile($a, $b, $c)` part right... It's just when you call it you want to use spaces between the parameters, not commas because the comma is the PowerShell array operator.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Functions in PowerShell are called similar to cmdlets, so you don't need to separate arguments with commas.

Your invocation likely looks like this:

```
getPropertyOfFile($foo, $bar, $baz)
```

which results in `$a` having the value `$foo, $bar, $baz` (an array) while `$b` and `$c` are `$null`.

You need to call it like this:

```
getPropertyOfFile $foo $bar $baz
```

which, as noted, is identical to how you call cmdlets. You could even do

```
getPropertyOfFile -a $foo -c $baz -b $bar
```

at which point you probably notice that your function arguments aren't named very well ;-)

**EDIT:** As noted before *your declaration of the function is **fine***. The problem is in the code *you didn't post* but is easily inferrable for people with PowerShell experience. Namely, the *invocation* of your function.

Comment: If I remove the commas it says: Missing ')' in function parameter list.

Comment: This is probably the culprit... unless `$a` is being created as an array somewhere.

Comment: *Invocation*, not *declaration*. Your declaration is fine (apart from the weird argument names).

Answer (score 3):

You need to separate your arguments when calling the function with spaces rather than commas i.e.

```
getPropertyOfFile $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
```

instead of

```
getPropertyOfFile $arg1, $arg2, $arg3
```

The second form will pass a single array containing `$arg1, $arg2` and `$arg3` as the parameter $a

Comment: I get: Missing function body in function declaration.
At line:1 char:28

Comment: @soandos - I mean when you call the function, not in the declaration